# Distinct and empty field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i executed this query but i don't understand why i get empty field `"",` in my result.

Why this {$ne : ""}) doesn't work?

Unfortunately, I also tried with `{$ne : null})` but the result is the same.

```
> db.logs.distinct('service_description', {host_name: "test"}, {$ne : ""})
[
    "",
    "Cpu",
    "Disks",
    "Mem",
    "Uptime",
    "VM Tools",
    "vm-alarm-CPU",
    "vm-alarm-MEM",
    "vm-alarm-VMTOOLS"
]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine both your query terms into a single object, and specify the field you want the `$ne` to apply to:

```
db.logs.distinct('service_description', {
    host_name: "test", 
    service_description: {$ne : ""}
})
```